# Why won't the grid of pictures on this page go to the center?

Tags: html, css

I've been playing around with a design for a photo website [here](http://jasperarmstrong.com) and I for some reason can't get the grid of pictures to center horizontally. I'm using PHP to count how many images there are on the server and then echoing them inside of a div, so that shouldn't be a reason for it to not be centering. Everything relevant to this (the page's html and css) should be able to be seen by viewing the source on the page. Thank you in advance for any help you give. :) (The pictures I used are from reddit.com/r/aww and are just placeholders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid is indeed centering horizontally, but you have it set to 97.5% width, so you don't really see the effect. Reduce the width to see that it does work. E.g.

```
#imgs {
   margin: 0.65% auto;
   width: 70%; /* was 97.5% */
}
```

Comment: i was about to the same thing - that was an easy ? to answer